# OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect

Tags: python, python-3.x, fabric, python-fabric-2

Trying to run python fabric 2 in windows 10

```
from fabric import task,SerialGroup,Connection
import os

USERNAME = os.getenv('USERNAME')
my_hosts = ["hostname"]
c = Connection(host="rg@host.com",connect_kwargs={"password":"abcd"})
@task
def test(c):
    print(USERNAME)
    c.run("echo hello")
```

Giving the below error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\users\rg\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line
> 194, in _run_module_as_main
> return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,                                                                      File "c:\users\rg\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line
> 87, in *run_code
>
> exec(code, run_globals)                                                                                         File
> "C:\Users\rg\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\fab.exe_*main**.py",
> line 7, in                File
> "c:\users\rg\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\invoke\program.py",
> line 384, in run
> self.execute()                                                                                                  File
> "c:\users\rg\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\invoke\program.py",
> line 566, in execute
> executor.execute(*self.tasks)                                                                                   File
> "c:\users\rg\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\invoke\executor.py",
> line 129, in execute
> result = call.task(*args, **call.kwargs)                                                                        File
> "c:\users\rg\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\invoke\tasks.py",
> line 127, in **call**
> result = self.body(*args, **kwargs)                                                                             File
> "C:\Users\rg\Documents\Solr\python_scripts\Solr\fabfiles\fabfile.py",
> line 10, in test
> c.run("echo hello")                                                                                             File
> "c:\users\rg\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\invoke\context.py",
> line 95, in run
> return self._run(runner, command, **kwargs)                                                                     File
> "c:\users\rg\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\invoke\context.py",
> line 102, in _run
> return runner.run(command, **kwargs)                                                                            File
> "c:\users\rg\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\invoke\runners.py",
> line 363, in run
> return self._run_body(command, **kwargs)                                                                        File
> "c:\users\rg\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\invoke\runners.py",
> line 411, in _run_body
> self.start(command, self.opts["shell"], self.env)                                                               File
> "c:\users\rg\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\invoke\runners.py",
> line 1271, in start
> self.process = Popen(                                                                                           File "c:\users\rg\programs\python\python38\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 858, in **init**
> self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,                                                    File "c:\users\rg\programs\python\python38\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 1311, in _execute_child
> hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,                                                    OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

This is a **sort-of-a-bug in fabric** (as of 2.6.0),
see the discussion here:
https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/2142

Apparently, it shows up with Python 3.8 or 3.9, but not with 3.6 or 3.7.

To get around it, you can use `c.run("echo hello", replace_env=False)`.

This is OK for local calls, but can be problematic for remote calls, because it means that the remote session will see all environment variable values (some of which may be sensitive) of your local session.